# Adding content to multiple classes with loops, but only 1 element from each class receive content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a grid of 6 big squares and inside each square there is 9 smaller squares.
Inner squares' classes are named i1, i2, i3 and so on.

So I created a loop to change textContent of class elements with:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++){
document.querySelector('.'+'i'+(i+1)).textContent = i+1;
}
```

HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row r1" style="background: red">
    <div class="square o1">
        <div class="isq i1"></div>
        <div class="isq i2"></div>
        <div class="isq i3"></div>
        <div class="isq i4"></div>
        <div class="isq i5"></div>
        <div class="isq i6"></div>
        <div class="isq i7"></div>
        <div class="isq i8"></div>
        <div class="isq i9"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="square o2">
        <div class="isq i1"></div>
        <div class="isq i2"></div>
        <div class="isq i3"></div>
        <div class="isq i4"></div>
        <div class="isq i5"></div>
        <div class="isq i6"></div>
        <div class="isq i7"></div>
        <div class="isq i8"></div>
        <div class="isq i9"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="square o3">
        <div class="isq i1"></div>
        <div class="isq i2"></div>
        <div class="isq i3"></div>
        <div class="isq i4"></div>
        <div class="isq i5"></div>
        <div class="isq i6"></div>
        <div class="isq i7"></div>
        <div class="isq i8"></div>
        <div class="isq i9"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

However only elements of "square o1" class received new content, rest of the squares didn't and it looks like this now:

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qw4Af.jpg)

My question is, how do I set new content to ALL items of these classes. But better question is how do I control it? In the future I will want to only alter the content of let's say "square o3" children classes, so I won't want to change all of them.

Edit:

Might be worth adding that I could only achieve adding textContent by using querySelector. It didn't work with getElementsByClassName or querySelectorAll and to be honest I don't know why.

Comment: have you tried `document.querySelectorAll()`?

Comment: It doesn't work at all then :) But it doesn't solve my future issues if I wanted to pick only classes of specific parent classes (i think)

Comment: jQuery lets you assign values to each element in a selector, but with normal javascript like this you'll have to iterate each item (from querySelectorAll) setting the textContent individually.

Comment: I want to stick with vanillaJS. Okay, I can live with selecting it manually but how do I select inner squares of let's say 3rd bigger square?

Comment: You can use a selector for that too, `document.querySelectorAll('.o3 .isq')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use another `for` loop, so it ends up being something like:

```
for(var o = 0; o < 3; o++){
  for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    document.querySelector('.o'+(o+1)+' .i'+(i+1)).textContent = i+1;
  }
}
```

And, if you want to do it only for certain group (let's say o3), then try:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++){
  document.querySelector('.o3 .i'+(i+1)).textContent = i+1;
}
```

Comment: Oh, so it's that simple with selecting children elements, thank you!

Comment: Yes it is. Also, keep in mind you can switch from `space`, between the classes, to `>` if you only want to match children elements rather than every descendant. You're welcome

Comment: Cool, glad I could help :P

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector()` Only returns the first element on the page. You are going to want to use `document.getElementsByClassName();`. This returns an array of all of the elements that have that class.

So you could:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    document.getElementsByClassName('i'+(i+1)).forEach(function(el) {
        el.textContent = i+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: When use `getElementsByClassName` you must not use dots. so your code should be like `i'+(i+1)` instead of `'.'+'i'+(i+1)`

Comment: This also works, but I enjoy the clarity of solution with nested loops someone posted below. I'm a beginner, but probably advanced programmers would prefer your solution

Comment: Mohamed Abbas you are totally right. I just fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Also you need to make another loop inside the big loop to cover `div`s with classes `o1`, `o2` and `o3`.

```js
for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++){
   var group = document.querySelectorAll('.'+'i'+(i+1));
   for (var j = 0; j < group.length; j ++) {
    group[j].textContent = i+1;
   }
   
}
// To get `<div class="square o3">`
alert(document.querySelector(".square.o3").innerHTML);
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row r1" style="background: red">
    <div class="square o1">
        <div class="isq i1"></div>
        <div class="isq i2"></div>
        <div class="isq i3"></div>
        <div class="isq i4"></div>
        <div class="isq i5"></div>
        <div class="isq i6"></div>
        <div class="isq i7"></div>
        <div class="isq i8"></div>
        <div class="isq i9"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="square o2">
        <div class="isq i1"></div>
        <div class="isq i2"></div>
        <div class="isq i3"></div>
        <div class="isq i4"></div>
        <div class="isq i5"></div>
        <div class="isq i6"></div>
        <div class="isq i7"></div>
        <div class="isq i8"></div>
        <div class="isq i9"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="square o3">
        <div class="isq i1"></div>
        <div class="isq i2"></div>
        <div class="isq i3"></div>
        <div class="isq i4"></div>
        <div class="isq i5"></div>
        <div class="isq i6"></div>
        <div class="isq i7"></div>
        <div class="isq i8"></div>
        <div class="isq i9"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks! Could you also help me with problem of how do I pick only i1, i2, i3... of parent element square o3 for example?

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector` returns a single element (the first found node).

If you want to loop the 3 elements that match the patternm you can either use `querySelectorAll` that will return an array ou loop the `.square` element and then the `iNUMBER` child.